# Win7/IE8 White Screen

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

After running a recovery on a new laptop (there were problems with the Turbo Boost and the manufacturer said running the recovery would solve them) I started getting a white screen in IE8 which had worked perfectly before the recovery.

I have:

- run the SFC scan
- uninstalled/reinstalled IE8
- deleted history, cookies, cache
- re-ran the recovery discs
- etc

but nothing works.

Initially the screen just went white and couldn't be refreshed, the only option was to close the tab.  But other times, when playing a game, the screen will refresh and restart the game.

If I turn off the anti-virus and spyware it seems to happen less but for obvious reasons that isn't a solution.  I've tried 3 different (Norton, Trend and McAfee) anti-virus programs but it still happens.

It worked before the recovery with all the same software, including anti-virus, but now it won't.  Also, I've updated the Flash and don't have this problem when using the Foxfire browser.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend switching to Firefox or Chrome -- frankly, that will likely be a lot easier than diagnosing the IE8 situation.

It'll also be faster and more secure!

So unless you have a specific reason to need IE8, I'd recommend switching browsers.